# How can I use my own image when site returns fake image with a 404 response code

Tags: javascript, html, image

This is a bit different then the usual question about how to gracefully handle broken images in javascript.

I already have an onerror handler on the image that will replace it with a custom "image not found" image.

However, there is a site that, when you request their image, returns a 404 response code, but in the response body actually returns an image with their own custom not found image.  Apparently, the img onerror event doesn't trigger in this case because there is still an image despite the error code.  (I tested on FireFox, IE8, and Chrome)

Here is a sample of the image in question: http://images.cars.com/preview/DMI/186445/C2121.jpg

Does anyone have any ideas for how to detect this case in javascript and replace their dynamic 404 image with our own?  Thanks!

Comment: What is your code for request/receiving the image?

Comment: `<img onerror="replaceImageUrl(this, 'http://myco.com/noImageAvailable.png', 150, 113)" onload="scaleImage(this, 150 , 113);" src="http://images.cars.com/phototab/DMI/186445/C2121.jpg"/>`

Comment: Would you be willing to use AJAX to get the image instead? EDIT: Gave me an answer 12 seconds before I asked my question.

Comment: And then I deleted my comment before I saw your response :)  (Wasn't sure without testing if I could use ajax because of cross domain)  But the original comment stands that for this use case I can't load all the images with ajax, nor double check each one after they are loaded via ajax.

Comment: Hahaha. Okay, so you want to use plain img tags, and possible a little javascript within the tags, right?

Comment: A better question may be "Detecting HTTP-header via JavaScript"

Comment: @feeela Perhaps, but would prefer it to remain specifically in the context of the normal img tag hooks.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution that comes to mind is not to load an image immediately, and then use javascript in document.ready or window.onload to get the image. Then, if the status is 404, put your own noImageAvailable.png in the image. If you get a 200 or other OK status, put the received image in there. There is a problem with this, however.

The same-origin policy does not allow scripts to access content cross-domain. So you would not be able to simply use javascript to get this file. There are a couple workarounds for this, one of which I will explain here (not necessarily the best, just an option).

The benefit of this method is that the javascript can just ask for a file, and display the result. The downside is more backend code. Simply have the javascript request the image from your server (AJAX), and insert the result in the img. On the server side for this request, open a TCP socket to the server hosting the image (you will have to resolve the IP address), and send an HTTP GET request for the image. If the image is returned ok, send it along as a response to the AJAX. If not, send your own noImageAvailable.png back.

Since this may take some time, you may want to replace the image with a default "loading" image at first, until the AJAX returns.

[AJAX Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

[HTTP Protocol Information](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

I'd include something on socket programming for you, but I don't know what kind of backend you are using.

Comment: Thanks @Jim.  Yes, the solution as you describe it would technically work, but given the volume of images, it is unfortunately not realistic for my situation.  Beyond just load and performance issues, it would likely trigger the 3rd party image host's denial of service/crawler detection algorithms since all the images would be loaded from a single IP. (And no I don't want to stick proxies in :)